# Image of linear transformation equal to eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question is as follows:

Suppose $A^2 = I$ (the identity matrix) and F = Q, R or C. Eigenvalues of A are then $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$. Show that $\ker(L (I+A))=E(-1)(A)$ and that $im(L (I+A))=E(1)(A)$.

$E(-1)(A)$ means eigenspace of eigenvalue $-1$.

I have managed to do the part with kernel, but I'm struggling with image and eigenspace.

I know how to prove that image is included in eigenspace $(E)$, but I don't know how to show the other way round.

Definition of $E$ I'm using: $E(1)(A) = \{x : Ax = x\}$.

Definition of image: $im(In + A) = \{y : y=(I + A)x\}$.

This is how I proved image is in eigenspace:
need to be shown: $Ay = y$

LHS: $Ay=A(I+A)x=A(Ix + Ax)=Ax + AAx= Ax + Ix=(A + I)x = y =$ RHS

Comment: What is $L$? The linear transformation $L(x)=Ax$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compute $(I+A)x$ for $x\in E(1)(A)$.

Comment: $(I+A)x = Ix + Ax = AA(x) + A(x)= A(A + I)x$ ?
or
$(I+A)x = Ix + Ax = x + x = 2x$ ?
something is wrong ...

Comment: Seems correct. Does the second equation help you to prove the statement you want to prove?

Comment: Would it be something like: $(I + A)x=2x=2Ax$
and then 
$A^2x - Ax=0$

how can it help me to show $y=(I+A)x$? i don't really know how and where I can find $y$?

Comment: Second hint: $L(I+A)$ is linear.

Comment: would it be like $(I+A)x=Ix+Ax=x+x=L(I)(x)+L(A)(x)=L(I+A)(x)=y?$

Comment: @rollerboller No, you need the reverse order. You need to find a $y$ such that $(I+A)y=x$.